# How to show a Userform after closing a second one with "X" button (Terminate Event breaks code)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 `Userforms`, `Userform1` and `Userform2`. I would to like to code `Userform2` so that when the user closes it using the `X` button on the top right corner, it closes and `Userform1` is automatically opened. The user can go from `Userform1` to `Userform2` with a `CommandButton` that has the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Unload Me
  UserForm2.Show

End Sub
```

After closing `Userform2`, I managed to automatically open `Userform1` with the following code in it:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

  UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

The problem is that this only works once. The second time the user clicks `CommandButton1`, `Userform1` is closed and `Userform2` showed, ***but*** Excel hangs up. The only way to fix it is to stop all the code from the developer environment or force quit Excel.

Using the `UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)` event isn't possible because that way, `Userform2` never reaches the `Unload` part and is just kept in the background while `Userform1` launches again, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to unload `UserForm1`. Simply hide it. Also there is no need to show `UserForm1` from `UserForm2`. It will automatically get shown when `UserForm2` unloads. Is this what you are trying?

**In a module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim frmOne As New UserForm1
    frmOne.Show
End Sub
```

**In Userform1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide '<~~ Hide the form
    
    Dim frmTwo As New UserForm2
    '~~> Show the form in Modal(default)
    frmTwo.Show
    
    '~~> Show UserForm1 when UserForm2 unloads
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> Thank you for taking the time to help me! Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I'm specifically trying to unload Userform1 when showing Userform2 and viceversa because I don't want/need to preserve any data. I know manually clearing the form would also work, but the other thing is that this is only an example. My real code has many forms and I don't want all of them to remain loaded in the memory. That could potentially cause some performance issues. – Fernanda 10 mins ago

This doesnt crash for me

**In a module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim frmOne As New UserForm1
    frmOne.Show
End Sub
```

**In Userform1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
    
    Dim frmTwo As New UserForm2
    frmTwo.Show
End Sub
```

**In Userform2**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Dim frmOne As New UserForm1
    frmOne.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I'm specifically trying to unload `Userform1` when showing `Userform2` and viceversa because I don't want/need to preserve any data. I know manually clearing the form would also work, but the other thing is that this is only an example. My real code has many forms and I don't want all of them to remain loaded in the memory. That could potentially cause some performance issues.

Comment: **1.** Even if you have many forms, there will only be 1 form hidden at a given time and not multiple forms unless I misynderstood you.. **2.**  Anyways, I updated the post. You may have to refresh it to see it

Comment: **1.** The issue is that I would like to implement this behavior for all the forms in the `Workbook`. Let's say the user clicks the "X" button on the third one, then the sixth, and so on. You can go from one to another with the buttons. Eventually all of them could just be hidden except the current one. Unless it is only possible to hide one form at the time I can imagine that scenario. **2.** Your new approach works flawlessly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)